# Installing linux-headers-4.4.10 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, apt

I am trying to install the linux-headers package on my Raspberry Pi, but am not finding any success.

I have tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.4.10
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.4.10'
```

And:

```
$ sudo apt-cache search linux-headers
linux-headers-3.10-3-all - All header files for Linux 3.10 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.10-3-all-armhf - All header files for Linux 3.10 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.10-3-common - Common header files for Linux 3.10-3
linux-headers-3.10-3-rpi - Header files for Linux 3.10-3-rpi
linux-headers-3.12-1-all - All header files for Linux 3.12 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.12-1-all-armhf - All header files for Linux 3.12 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.12-1-common - Common header files for Linux 3.12-1
linux-headers-3.12-1-rpi - Header files for Linux 3.12-1-rpi
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-all - All header files for Linux 3.16 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-all-armhf - All header files for Linux 3.16 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common - Common header files for Linux 3.16.0-4
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-rpi - Header files for Linux 3.16.0-4-rpi
linux-headers-3.18.0-trunk-all - All header files for Linux 3.18 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.18.0-trunk-all-armhf - All header files for Linux 3.18 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.18.0-trunk-common - Common header files for Linux 3.18.0-trunk
linux-headers-3.18.0-trunk-rpi - Header files for Linux 3.18.0-trunk-rpi
linux-headers-3.18.0-trunk-rpi2 - Header files for Linux 3.18.0-trunk-rpi2
linux-headers-3.6-trunk-all - All header files for Linux 3.6 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.6-trunk-all-armhf - All header files for Linux 3.6 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.6-trunk-common - Common header files for Linux 3.6-trunk
linux-headers-3.6-trunk-rpi - Header files for Linux 3.6-trunk-rpi
linux-headers-4.4.0-1-all - All header files for Linux 4.4 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.4.0-1-all-armhf - All header files for Linux 4.4 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.4.0-1-common - Common header files for Linux 4.4.0-1
linux-headers-4.4.0-1-rpi - Header files for Linux 4.4.0-1-rpi
linux-headers-4.4.0-1-rpi2 - Header files for Linux 4.4.0-1-rpi2
linux-headers-rpi - Header files for Linux rpi configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-rpi-rpfv - This metapackage will pull in the headers for the raspbian kernel for the
linux-headers-rpi2-rpfv - This metapackage will pull in the headers for the raspbian kernel for the
```

Is there simply no valid linux-headers package available? Should I try installing one of the linux-headers-4.4.0-1 packages?

Answer (score 2):

Since You didnt mention what kind of OS You are running on Your raspi but used `apt-get`, i assume You are running some version of raspbian. Did You try searching for available headers `apt-cache search linux-headers`? Also, a full update `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` might be useful.

By the way, I think You might be wrong here, since there is a stack community entirely devoted to the reaspberry pi. Check out https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ , Im sure they can provide better help for You.
Looks like they also already discussed this issue. Some useful links:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37589/where-do-i-find-the-linux-headers-for-an-image

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=57401

Hope I could help You out. Happy coding :3

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Raspbian-headers with:

```
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

After installing this package you will find the headers here: */lib/modules//*